# React component in html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I think I didn't understand the concept of ReactJS. I thought I could write "custom tags" with it. For example, I could make an input field, with some extra functionality, so that I could use it as follows:-

```
<form id="theForm">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />

    <my-input-field />
    <my-input-field />
    <my-input-field />

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

As I understand it, I must pass "theForm" to my component which renders the complete form, right? Custom tags are only allowed inside the JSX render function?

If I want many components on one page, I have to call the ReactDOM.render() method for each element? Like so:

HTML:

```
<form id="theForm">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />

    <input id="custom-1" />
    <input id="custom-2" />
    <input id="custom-3" />

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
ReactDOM.render(<my-input-field />, document.getElementById("custom-1"));
ReactDOM.render(<my-input-field />, document.getElementById("custom-2"));
ReactDOM.render(<my-input-field />, document.getElementById("custom-3"));
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Custom components must be capitalized or they will be treated as DOM elements

Comment: I think you may need to go over the docs again. You will render your main/root component to a block element (commonly a div with id of "app" in tutorials). Your child components (that can contain forms, paragraphs, list, etc.) will be rendered within the parent component. You need to think modular. React has a nice [tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html).

Comment: As you re-read the tutorial, keep in mind that the pattern is to use ReactDOM.render just once for your root element.  Then construct your children elements from there, usually using `map` for repeated elements.

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes. Okey, the form has to be the root container and all inner elements must be placed inside the render function. Not what i want - if i want to spread some components in my page, i have to call ReactDOM.render() for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found what i want - the same component multiple times in a page. In my example i have an custom input field, but i don't want the whole form to be a component.

HTML:

```
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="">
            <div class="my-input-field" data-myprop="First" ></div>
            <input type="text" name="">
            <input type="text" name="">
            <div class="my-input-field" data-myprop="Second" ></div>
            <input type="text" name="">
            <div class="my-input-field" data-myprop="Third" ></div>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
```

index.tsx:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { MyInputField } from "./components/MyInputField";

let myInputFields = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("my-input-field"));
for (let element of myInputFields) {
    ReactDOM.render(<MyInputField myprop={element.dataset.myprop} />, element)
}
```

MyInputField.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface MyInputFieldProps  {
    myprop: string;
}

export class MyInputField extends React.Component<MyInputFieldProps, undefined> {
    render() {
        return (
            <input value={this.props.myprop}/>
        );
    }
}
```

Is is a bad practice to call the render method in loop?

THX